# Reorganizing and collapsing many csv's in R

Tags: r

I am working with R.

My data looks like this...

```
un01 <- structure(list(...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"), hill = c(2.26315789473684, 
                                                       38, 2.0623289187203), user = c(1.13157894736842, 38, 1.57978877533674
                                                       ), name = c(2.42105263157895, 38, 1.96773403700762), paint = c(4.18421052631579, 
                                                                                                                               38, 1.81369062527503), smile = c(6.05263157894737, 38, 1.98572430003074
                                                                                                                               ), back = c(4.10526315789474, 38, 2.0767629916461), mouse = c(7.35135135135135, 
                                                                                                                                                                                             38, 1.75144727798686), potato = c(5.94736842105263, 38, 2.01276156159657
                                                                                                                                                                                             ), pain = c(1.34210526315789, 38, 1.69699759972873), life = c(4.05263157894737, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      38, 1.99928863593695)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is a summary of my data. My real data contains 3 observations and 160 variables. I also have 25 different csv's.

The name of the csv's are:

un01
un02
un03
un04
un05
pm01...pm05
kl01...
jp01...
tr01...
(25 csv's)

Every cvs is organized in the same manner. Every csv that contains the code 01 has the same words, this mean that if the un01 (the one I am sahring above) has the words: hill, user, name, paint, smile, back, mouse, potato, pain, life. Then, all the 01 (pm01, kl01, ...) contain this very same words. However, they are in different documents because they are different variables.

So, what I need is my output to look like this...

```
word     un_mean  un_n  un_SD  pm_mean  pm_n  pm_SD  kl_mean  kl_n  kl_SD ...rest of the variables
hill
user
name
paint
smile
back
mouse
potato
pain 
life
*This first 10 words are the same for every 01 version
word one (1) of every variable coded with 02
word two of every variable coded with 02
word three of of every variable coded with 02
" " until word 10 of every variable coded with 02
" " same with every variable until you reach 05


Then you will reach to the total of words
```

So, I need the words in a single column and their values in each variable. This means that each row is an observation/word and then we have the value of that word on each variable (un, pm, kl, jp, tr)

How can I do this?

****ONE thing I forgot, the documents that are coded with a 05 do not contain the same amount of words as the rest of the document. So they contain 6 columns less.

adding un05 and pm01

un05

```
un05 <- structure(list(...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"), house = c(5.08823529411765, 
                                                              34, 1.65817802638964), person = c(4.11764705882353, 34, 2.15694376772143
                                                              ), city = c(2.47058823529412, 34, 1.70978102651927), agressive = c(5, 
                                                                                                                                      34, 1.95401684183679)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

pm01

```
pm01 <- structure(list(...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"), hill = c(5.3030303030303, 
                                                         33, 1.64857606142484), user = c(4.24242424242424, 33, 1.96898297082375
                                                         ), name = c(7.18181818181818, 33, 1.18465568453838), 
               paint = c(3.27272727272727, 33, 1.71887912738082), 
               smile = c(1.15151515151515, 33, 4.8728523053289), back = c(4.3030303030303, 
                                                                             33, 2.02306772756204), mouse = c(7.06060606060606, 33, 1.57994054356869
                                                                             ), potato = c(3.34666666666667, 33, 1.36289077492212), pain = c(4.17666666666667, 
                                                                                                                                             33, 1.25762044965971), life = c(4.22121212121212, 33, 1.40884650861919
                                                                                                                                             )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                             ))
```

Comment: Question: what value do you want for when the word does not exist in the CSV?  My instinct would be `NA` for "blank", but then again, there might already be `NA`s in your dataset...

Comment: I don't understadn the question. Every word exist within the correspodnign code (01 = one specifc group of words, 02 = one specific gorup of words, ...). I am not sure what you mean, but every word has a mean value, n and SD. There is no result with NA's within the columns os results per variable.

Comment: Ohhh, I see.  Since every `un` or `pm` has an `01` version, and since every `01` version has the word `"hill"`, then we only need to show `"hill"` once under `word`, and every column (like `un_*` or `pm_*`) will have a value for `"hill"`.

Comment: yes, that is right, only one time, then the values of that word per variable

Comment: I am going to fix this on the table above, It is a mistake to separate them.

Comment: I think I have a nice solution in the **`tidyverse`**.  Could you please provide `dput(un05)` and `dput(pm01)`, so I can test it?

Comment: In one moment @Greg

Comment: I just added the data @Greg

Comment: I just finished [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70583381).  Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an elegant solution in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org/), without any cumbersome looping. It assumes that all the variables {`un01`, ..., `un05`, `pm01`, ..., `pm05`, ..., `tr01`, ..., `tr05`} exist as `data.frame`s in your workspace; though it could be easily modified to accommodate another situation.

## Warning

Be sure to use [version 1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580858/reorganizing-and-collapsing-many-csvs-in-r/70583381#comment124934088_70583381) (or later) of the **`tidyverse`**; and especially [version 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138928) (or later) of the [**`tidyr`**](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) package.

## Solution

```
# Use the tidyverse.
library(tidyverse)
```

First create the `standardize_csv()` function like so:

```
# Function to transform CSVs into a standard form.
standardize_csv <- function(csv_data, csv_prefix){
  # Turn the word columns into a single column.
  csv_data %>% pivot_longer(
    # The word columns are every column except the 1st, which names the metric.
    cols = !1,
    names_to = "word"
  ) %>%
    # Include the CSV prefix for reference.
    mutate(
      csv_prefix = csv_prefix
    ) %>%
    # Rename and reformat the dataset.
    select(
      csv_prefix,
      word,
      metric = 1,
      value
    )
}
```

Then construct a *named* `list()` of all your CSV datasets, where the names follow your convention: `"un01"`, ..., `"un05"`, ..., `"tr01"`, ..., `"tr05"`.  Here, we [`get()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/get.html) those datasets from your workspace.

```
# Find all CSV variables named by your convention, within your workspace.
csv_list <- sapply(
  X = ls(pattern = "^[a-z]{2,2}0[1-5]$"),
  FUN = get,
  simplify = FALSE,
  USE.NAMES = TRUE
)
```

Armed with `standardize_csv()`, you can do the rest in a single workflow:

```
# Consolidate into the final form:
final_df <- csv_list %>%
  mapply(
    # Transform into standard form...
    FUN = standardize_csv,
    # ...the CSV datasets...
    csv_data = .,
    # ...with their prefixes.
    csv_prefix = gsub(
      x = names(.),
      pattern = "^([a-z]*)(\\d*)$",
      replacement = "\\1"
    ),
    
    SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  ) %>%
  # Stack those standardized datasets into a single table.
  do.call(
    what = bind_rows
  ) %>%
  # Pivot the table to have one column for each family and metric ('un_mean',
  # 'pm_SD', etc.).
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(csv_prefix, metric),
    names_glue = "{csv_prefix}_{metric}",
    values_from = value
  )

# View the result.
final_df
```

## Result

Given the CSV variables {`un01`, `un05`, `pm01`} that you sampled

```
un01 <- structure(
  list(
    ...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"),
    hill = c(2.26315789473684, 38, 2.0623289187203),
    user = c(1.13157894736842, 38, 1.57978877533674),
    name = c(2.42105263157895, 38, 1.96773403700762),
    paint = c(4.18421052631579, 38, 1.81369062527503),
    smile = c(6.05263157894737, 38, 1.98572430003074),
    back = c(4.10526315789474, 38, 2.0767629916461),
    mouse = c(7.35135135135135, 38, 1.75144727798686),
    potato = c(5.94736842105263, 38, 2.01276156159657),
    pain = c(1.34210526315789, 38, 1.69699759972873),
    life = c(4.05263157894737, 38, 1.99928863593695)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

un05 <- structure(
  list(
    ...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"),
    house = c(5.08823529411765, 34, 1.65817802638964),
    person = c(4.11764705882353, 34, 2.15694376772143),
    city = c(2.47058823529412, 34, 1.70978102651927),
    agressive = c(5, 34, 1.95401684183679)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

pm01 <- structure(
  list(
    ...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD"),
    hill = c(5.3030303030303, 33, 1.64857606142484),
    user = c(4.24242424242424, 33, 1.96898297082375),
    name = c(7.18181818181818, 33, 1.18465568453838),
    paint = c(3.27272727272727, 33, 1.71887912738082),
    smile = c(1.15151515151515, 33, 4.8728523053289),
    back = c(4.3030303030303, 33, 2.02306772756204),
    mouse = c(7.06060606060606, 33, 1.57994054356869),
    potato = c(3.34666666666667, 33, 1.36289077492212),
    pain = c(4.17666666666667, 33, 1.25762044965971),
    life = c(4.22121212121212, 33, 1.40884650861919)),
  row.names = c(NA, -3L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

the result for `final_df` should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 7
   word      pm_mean  pm_n pm_SD un_mean  un_n un_SD
   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 hill         5.30    33  1.65    2.26    38  2.06
 2 user         4.24    33  1.97    1.13    38  1.58
 3 name         7.18    33  1.18    2.42    38  1.97
 4 paint        3.27    33  1.72    4.18    38  1.81
 5 smile        1.15    33  4.87    6.05    38  1.99
 6 back         4.30    33  2.02    4.11    38  2.08
 7 mouse        7.06    33  1.58    7.35    38  1.75
 8 potato       3.35    33  1.36    5.95    38  2.01
 9 pain         4.18    33  1.26    1.34    38  1.70
10 life         4.22    33  1.41    4.05    38  2.00
11 house       NA       NA NA       5.09    34  1.66
12 person      NA       NA NA       4.12    34  2.16
13 city        NA       NA NA       2.47    34  1.71
14 agressive   NA       NA NA       5       34  1.95
```

### Note

Since no `pm_05` was available, there are "blanks" (`NA`s) for the corresponding words under the `pm_*` columns. This illustrates how missing CSVs are handled, but as long as you provide all the CSV variables, there should be no blanks in your full result.

Comment: When I execute the final_df code and error jumps.  Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = c(csv_prefix, metric), names_glue = "{csv_prefix}_{metric}",  : 
  unused argument (names_glue = "{csv_prefix}_{metric}")

Comment: @Ajrhmamd I tried it from scratch in R, and it did work for me. Did you copy the code exactly?  And do all the CSV variables {`un01`, ..., `un05`, `pm01`, ..., `pm05`, ..., `tr01`, ..., `tr05`} exist as `data.frame`s in your global environment?

Comment: that might be the problem, I was using read_csv I think those are tibbles. right?

Comment: **NEVER MIND**.  I think the issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138928.  It looks like the `names_glue` argument is only available in later versions of the [**`tidyr`**](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) package, so if you're using an older version, you'll get the error: `unused argument (names_glue = "{csv_prefix}_{metric}")`.  **Have you updated the `tidyr` package?**

Comment: Ok, I think that was affecting the result. However, now I get this error
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `...1` doesn't exist.

Comment: How is your metric column named?  Your sample data begins with the column `...1`, as shown here: `un01 <- structure(list(...1 = c("mean", "n", "SD")`.  Is this still the case in your CSV data, or is it named something else now?

Comment: Ok now I know, In my data the first column is X and not ...1, I did not change this name. Apparently it change with dput or something because I did not changed that name. I am goin to change the code when a ...1 appears.

Comment: @Ajrhmamd Good to know.  You could also replace `...1` with `1` in the code for `standardize_csv()`, so the `1`st column will always be used, regardless of its name.

Comment: That sound good, let me see

Comment: Hey, I just saw your warning but I had version 1.3.0 and it was not working. I needed to install 1.3.1

It worked perfectly!!

Comment: @Ajrhmamd Glad to hear it!  Thanks for accepting my answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think one good starting point could be to load all needed files in a list and all names of the files in another list or vector, e.g. something like

```
names2use <- list.files(path2direcitonwherefilesare)
fileList <- lapply(names2use, function(x) { read.csv(file.path(path2direcitonwherefilesare, x), ...)
```

Then you can create a matrix/data.frame an fill it up, e.g.

```
#my dummy data set
un01 <- data.frame(types=c("mean", "sd"), hill=c(0.1,0.2), boat=c(0.1,0.2))
un02 <- data.frame(types=c("mean", "sd"), trip=c(0.1,0.2), clip=c(0.1,0.2))
jp01 <- data.frame(types=c("mean", "sd"), hill=c(0.1,0.2), boat=c(0.1,0.2))
fileList <- list(un01, un02, jp01)
filenames <- c("un01", "un02", "jp01")

types <- unique(substr(filenames, start = 1, stop = 2))
infos <- as.character(un01[,1])
names2use <- c(paste(types, sort(rep(infos, length(types))), sep="_"))
rows <- unique(unlist(lapply(fileList, function(x) {names(x)})))[-1]

#creating empty an data.frame
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=length(cols), ncol=length(names2use)+1))
data[,1] <- rows
names(data) <- c("word", sort(names2use))

i <- 1
for (file in fileList) {
  filename <- substr(filenames[[i]],1,2)
  for (n in 2:length(names(file))) {
    data[data$word==names(file)[n], substr(names(data),1,2) %in% filename] <- file[[names(file)[n]]]
  }
  i <- i + 1
}

> data
  word jp_mean jp_sd un_mean un_sd
1 hill     0.1   0.2     0.1   0.2
2 boat     0.1   0.2     0.1   0.2
3 trip      NA    NA     0.1   0.2
4 clip      NA    NA     0.1   0.2
```